# Moment.js - translate local month names to en-gb

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have an array with month names in locale (e.g. ianuare, februarie, martie, aprilie, mai, iunie, iulie...) and I want to translate it to en-gb locale (January, February, March...). This is my code snippet I am using:

```
    let months = [...momentLocaleObject.months(), ...momentLocaleObject.monthsShort()]
    months.map((n) => {
        dateMap.get(RULE_ENTITIES.MONTHS).set(n, moment().month(n).locale('en-gb').format('MMMM'));
    });
```

The problem is that it is not working properly and some months are not translated correctly (please see attached picture). Can I ask you about any help?

Edit: JSFiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/ef9bmng7/

[image]

Comment: What `dateMap` and `RULE_ENTITIES.MONTHS` are? Maybe adding a snippet or a fiddle showing your issue would help you getting a useful answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I tried to simplify that but the result is the same: https://jsfiddle.net/ef9bmng7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moment by default uses `en` locale.

In your code `n` is the name of the month in the given locale, you have to set locale properly to make [`month()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/) work.

```
moment().month('ianuarie')
```

is not valid if current locale is `en`, while this will work:

```
// Setting locale locally
moment().locale('ro').month('ianuarie')
// Setting locale globally
moment.locale('ro');
moment().month('ianuarie');
```

See [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/) more detailed info on setting locale in moment.

Here a working version of your fiddle, as exaplained, I've just added `locale(key)`before using `month(n)`:

```js
const countriesMap = new Map();

const roMap = new Map();
const roMapSpecials = new Map();
const roMapDate = new Map();
const roMapWeekdays = new Map();
const roMapMonths = new Map();

countriesMap.set('ro', roMap);

//roMap.set('Specials', roMapSpecials);
//roMapDate.set('Weekdays', roMapWeekdays);
roMapDate.set('Months', roMapMonths);
roMap.set('Date', roMapDate);

for (let pair of countriesMap) {
 let [key, value] = pair;
 let momentLocaleObject = moment.localeData(key);
 let dateMap = value.get('Date');
  
let months = [...momentLocaleObject.months(), ...momentLocaleObject.monthsShort()]
months.map((n) => {
 dateMap.get('Months').set(n, moment().locale(key).month(n).locale('en-gb').format('MMMM'));
});
}

console.log(countriesMap.get('ro').get('Date').get('Months'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```